# Как реализовать функцию, которая суммирует все элементы массива, используя рекурсию

Tags: javascript

Я уже реализовал данную функцию используя циклы, но у меня не получается реализовать данную функцию используя рекурсию. Консоль выдает значение Nan, т.к он складывает общую сумму со значением undefined. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную проблему

```
let arr = [ 2, 4, 6 ];

// функция реализованная рекурсией
function Sum(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0)
    return arr[0];
    else
        console.log(arr[0]);
        arr.splice(0, 1); // начиная с позиции 0, удалить 1 элемент
        console.log(arr[0]);
    return arr[0] + Sum(arr); 
}

// функция реализованная циклом
// function Sum() {
//  var result = 0;
//  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
//      result += arr[i];
//  }
//  return result;
// }

console.log(Sum(arr));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [2, 4, 6];

function Sum(arr) {
  return arr.length? arr.splice(0, 1)[0] + Sum(arr) : 0;
}

console.log("result =", Sum(arr));
```

```js
let arr = [2, 4, 6];

let Sum = a => a.length? a.pop() + Sum(a) : 0;

console.log("result =", Sum(arr));
```

Comment: `let Sum arr => a.length ? a.pop() + Sum(a) : 0`;

Comment: @StrangerintheQ тоже хорошо

Comment: Получился без одной неточности Ваш вариант, поэтому он тут)

Comment: @Igor у меня такой вопрос. Что значит [0] в arr.splice(0, 1)[0] ? Т.е. программа запоминает нулевой элемент массива в памяти и сразу же удаляет нулевой элемент из массива, который в свою очередь идет на рекурсию в Sum()? И так будет продолжаться до тех пор пока a.length не станет false (будет = 0) и не вернет 0 (return 0)?

Comment: @Danila00000 `splice` возвращает массив удаленных элементов, в данном случае - массив из одного элемента с индексом 0.

Comment: @Igor все понял, спасибо)